# Java 8 Map computeIfPresent boolean check inside Bifunction

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

This is the pre-Java 8 way of the code,

```
Album testAlbum = (Album) testMap.get(testField);

List < Album > testList = new ArrayList();

if (testAlbum != null) {
 if (isFree) {
  if (applyFreeFilter(testAlbum)) {
   testList.add(testAlbum);
  }
 } else {
  testList.add(testAlbum);
 }
}
```

Trying to use compute if Present, to avoid the multiple if else, but stuck.

IS it a overkill, or i am missing something in the BiFunction to process the value out of the map?

```
testMap.computeIfPresent(testField, (k, v) -> {
 if (isFree) {
  if (applyFreeFilter((Album) v)) {
   testList.add((Album) v);
  }
 } else {
  testList.add((Album) v);
 }
});
```

Comment: I suggest you generics so you don't need to cash the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A part of your code is definitely an overkill.
It can be as simple as that:

```
if(!isFree || applyFreeFilter((Album) v)) {
    testList.add((Album) v);
 }
```

If `isFree` is `false`, then `applyFreeFilter` is not executed and you can save time.

As regards the `if (testAlbum != null)` check, it's not bad, but you can wrap your `testAlbum` in `Optional<Album>` instead, then you can write `testAlbum.ifPresent(theAlbum -> doSomething(theAlbum));`. I think you make no use of the `k` variable... so `computeIfPresent` is a bit of an overkill in your code as well.

To wrap up my solution would be:

```
Optional<Album> testAlbum = Optional.ofNullable((Album) testMap.get(testField));
final List <Album> testList = new ArrayList();
testAlbum.ifPresent(theAlbum -> {
    if(!isFree || applyFreeFilter((Album) theAlbum))
        testList.add((Album) theAlbum);
});
```

6 lines of code instead of initial 13.

Comment: Doesn't `!isFree || applyFreeFilter` do it ?

Comment: @GPI, yes it does :) Thank you.